# codepen css not displaying when exported

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, bootstrap-4

Hi there i am very new to coding and have been learning at free code camp for a couple weeks now (3-4 weeks), about 10 hours a week as i only get chance to code when i get home at nights after work, so please bear with me if my mistakes might seem amateur-ish.

Ok, so my issue is, i started a draft for a portfolio page on codepen. Its currently not finish but midway i decided to export it and see how it runs outside of codepen. When i exported it runs perfect on google chrome on my local pc, however i sent the html exported file to two separate pcs and when the file was opened the web page was nothing like how it was opening on my pc. The css dont seem to be working.Back ground images are missing, images that had css classes applied to them seemed to be not effective, fonts seemed to be overridden by default fonts

here is a link to my code pen:
[enter link description here](https://codepen.io/Lerts/pen/RMeLPO)

```
<header>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Black+Han+Sans" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Gugi" rel="stylesheet">
</header>
<body class="boDy">
<div class="myDiv">
    <div class="bg"></div>
    <h1 class="myfont2 text-center"> <span style="color:purple">T.E.Q</span> 
    <span style="color:green">MOLECULE</span> MEDIA</h1>
</div>
<nav id="nav-example" class="navbar navbar-inverse bg-dark affix sticky" data-target-offset="18">  
    <a class="navbar-brand myfont" href="#">TEQ Molecule</a>
    <ul class="nav nav-pills">
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#Portfolio">Portfolio</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link " href="#About">About</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown</a>
            <div class="dropdown-menu">
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#Contact">Contact</a>
        </li> 
        </div>
    </ul>
</nav>
<div class="bckground">
    <div class="bb1"></div>
    <br></br>
    <br></br>
    <br></br>
<div id="#scroller" data-spy="scroll" data-target="#nav-example" data-offset="10">
    <div class="myfont2" id="About" style="left:20px">
        <br></br>
        <h3>ABOUT T.E.Q</h3> 
    </div>
<img class="smallerImage"style="margin-left:20px"src="http://farm1.staticflickr.com/860/40814758834_31a56037fb_b.jpg" alt="about TEQ">
<br></br>
<br></br>

<div class="divider"></div>
<br></br>

<div id="Portfolio" class="myfont2">
    <br></br>
    <h3>PORTFOLIO</h3>
</div>
<br></br>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <a href="#"> <img class="thumbnail imgCenter" src="http://farm1.staticflickr.com/842/41527921141_e5c1bdbd42_b.jpg" alt="graphic arts"></a>
        <p class="text-center myfont"> GRAPHIC DESIGN</p>
    </div>
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <a href="#"> <img class="thumbnail imgCenter"  src="https://f9tech.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/02/dev-1.jpg" alt="web deveopment"></a>
        <p class="text-center myfont"> WEB DEVELOPMENT</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <a href="#"><img class="thumbnail imgCenter" align="center" src="https://scontent.fbgi2-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-9/25299007_1255958357881913_5312854462633629399_n.jpg?_nc_cat=0&oh=0c924733b42ea92b9916ab8576192094&oe=5B59AE75" alt="digital marketing"></a>
        <p class="text-center myfont">DIGITAL MARKETING</p>
    </div>
</div>
    <br></br>
    <div class="divider2"></div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: sorry for how messy my layout is

Comment: I've edited the question and it has HUGE tag problems

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to share not only the HTML with the other computers, but all the folders and files inside your project, eg: css files, images, etc.

Comment: oh my goodness, *facepalm* that did not cross my mind. Thank you

Comment: Ha, no worries, We all had those kind of problems at the beginning.

Comment: So is there a way that i can compile this into one file if i wanted to send it to someone who wants to view it, without me having to attach these other folders?

Comment: you could try deploying it to a server, if you know how to use GitHub you could try that [github pages] (https://pages.github.com/) it's free.
You could also try to zip the folder and send the whole project to someone, the idea is to have it deployed somewhere though.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do many things for your code works.

- Change you tag called  to

[image]

- Create two folders in your project width the following names: css and js. In css folder create a file called style.css and add your style code in css. In js folder create a file called main.js and add your script code in js

[image]

- Your project needs import jquery and bootstrap libs. So, you need put in head tag the following path cdn

[image]

Notice that there are links of your css and js files

Complete code here